# Can't integrate secure cookies into my login php system

Tags: php, authentication, pdo, session-cookies

I have read many articles concerning secure cookies and downloaded a lot of code samples. I tried to integrate it into my login system but in vain.

I have sessions and they work just fine.

Also I use PHP PDO here because it is more safe than mysqli. I don't know whether it can influence cookies integration or not.

Let me show you my code where I tried to integrate cookies.

login.php

```
<html> 
<head>
<?php
require_once("meta.inc");
?>
</head>
<body>
<a href="index.php">Back to the index page</a><br/><br/>

<?php
 //Show message after registration that user can login with a generated password
 if($_GET['message']) {
 $message = $_GET['message'];
 echo $message;
 }
 ?>

  <form class="bootstrap-frm" name="register" method="post" action="loginprocess.php">
    <h1>Login</h1>
      <?php
      if (isset($_GET['both'])) {
      echo "Both the email and password should be submitted";
      }
      ?>
      <?php
      if (isset($_GET['failed'])) {
      echo "No such email exist or wrong password";
      }
      ?>
      <label>
      <?php
      if (isset($_GET['invalid_email'])) {
      echo "Enter a valid email";
      }
      ?>
      <span>Email:</span>     
      <input type="email" id="name"  placeholder="Enter your email" name="email" />
      </label>

      <label>
      <?php
      if (isset($_GET['pass_4'])) {
      echo "Your password should be more than 4";
      }
      ?>
      <span>Password:</span> 
     <input type="password" id="email" placeholder="Enter your password" name="password" />
     </label>

     <label>
  <span>Remember Me</span>
  <input type="checkbox" name="autologin" value="1">
  </label><br/>

    <label>
    <span>&nbsp;</span> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="button">
    </label>

  </form>
  <p>Forgot your password? Click <a href="forgot_password.php">Here</a></p>

  <?php
  require_once("footer.inc");
  ?>
 </body> 
 </html>
```

loginprocess.php

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

session_start(); // Start Session
header('Cache-control: private'); // IE 6 FIX

// always modified
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . ' GMT');
// HTTP/1.1
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
// HTTP/1.0
header('Pragma: no-cache');


// ---------- Cookie Info ---------- //

$cookie_name = 'siteAuth';
$cookie_time = (3600 * 24 * 30); // 30 days

//Set necessary variables
$email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$password = filter_var($_POST['password'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$autologin = $_POST['autologin'];


// check that both the email, password have been submitted 
if(!isset($email, $password)) {
header("Location: login.php?both=" . urlencode($both));
}

if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
header("Location: login.php?invalid_email=" . urlencode($invalid_email));
}

// check the password length 
elseif(strlen($_POST['password']) < 5) {
header("Location: login.php?pass_4=" . urlencode($pass_4));
}


else {

      // now we can encrypt the password 
      $password = sha1($password);

      require("includes/config.php");
      $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email AND password = :password");

        // bind the parameters 
        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR, 40); 

        // execute the prepared statement 
        $stmt->execute();

        //check if there is nos such a email in the database
        $row = $stmt->rowCount();

        if ($row == false) {
        header("Location: login.php?failed=" . urlencode($failed));
        }

        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

         if($row['user_id'] == 67) {   
         // if it is admin account then create S_SESSION['admin'] in order to use it  everywhere on the site and redirect to the admin page after successful login
               $_SESSION['admin'] = $row['user_id'];         
               header("Location: index.php"); 
          }

         elseif ($row['user_id'] != 67) {

         if($autologin == 1) {

         $password_hash = sha1($password); 

          // if we do have a result, redirect to the index.php page
               $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
               $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
             $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
               setcookie ($cookie_name, 'eml='.$_SESSION['email'].'&hash='.$password_hash, time() + $cookie_time);         
               header("location: index.php");
            }
         } 
     }
 }

$db = null;

?>
```

Comment: I did it by myself...